# How to get integer value from string with fix position

Tags: php

I want to get 330 from a string using regular expression.

My string is `transform: rotate(330deg)`

Comment: Well, just use RegEx to extract the numeric part of the string and then cast it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
preg_match('/transform\:\srotate\((-?\d+)deg\)/', $str, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

Comment: well this is working on positive value if I have a string "transform: rotate(-330deg)" its not work.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if your string is only `transform: rotate(330deg)`, the easiest solution will be filetring everything other than the numbers out.

```
// Using filter_var ( supports negative values )

$str = 'transformcase: rotate(-330deg)';
$rotationValue = filter_var($str, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function get_rotate($string) {
  $regex = '/^transform\:[ ]*rotate\((\d+)deg[ ]*\)$/';
  if (preg_match($regex, $string)) {
    return (int) preg_replace($regex, '$1', $string);
  }
  return false;
}

echo get_rotate($string);
```